# sqlalchemy postgresql where int = string

Tags: python, sqlite, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have 0 experience with postgresql and am deploying an app written in python using sqlalchemy to a server with postgres.

For development, I used an sqlite server.

Things are going pretty smoothly, but I hit a bump I don't know how to resolve.

I have three tables that look like that

```
class Car(db.Model):
     id= db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
     ...

class Truck(db.Model):
     id= db.Column(db.String(32), primary_key=True)
     ...

class Vehicles(db.Model):
     id= db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
     type= db.Column(db.String) #This is either 'car' or 'truck'
     value= db.Column(db.String) #That's the car or truck id
     ...
```

I have a query that selects from `Vehicles` where `type = 'car' AND value = 10`
This is throwing an error:
`sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (ProgrammingError) operator does not exist: integer = character varying`

So I guess this is because  `Car.id` is an int and `Vehicle.value` is a string..

How to write this query in sqlalchemy? Is there a way to write it and make it compatible with my sqlite dev environment and the pgsql production?

currently it looks like that

`db.session.query(Vehicle).filter(Car.id == Vehicle.value)`

PS: The truck id has to be a string and the car id has to be an int. I don't have control over that.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Simply cast to a string:

```
db.session.query(Vehicle).filter(str(Car.id) == Vehicle.value)
```

if `Car.id` is a local variable that is an int.

If you need to use this in a join, have the database cast it to a string:

```
from sqlalchemy.sql.expression import cast

db.session.query(Vehicle).filter(cast(Car.id, sqlalchemy.String) == Vehicle.value)
```

If the string value in the other column contains digits *and possibly whitespace* you may have to consider trimming, or instead casting the string value to an integer (and leave the integer column an integer).

Comment: @chaft: **If** `Truck.id` holds a string that represents an integer - i.e. only digits (and possibly leading / trailing white space) and can be cast to integer - then you are better off casting `Truck.id::int` than the other way round (`Car.id::varchar`). Also note that yout get different results if your strings contain leading / trailing white space, because that's trimmed in a cast to `integer`, but makes a difference when comparing `varchar` or `text`.