# How to force sqlalchemy to use big int for specific and clause

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, python-3.8

I have this code

```
my_query = query.filter(
    sa.and_(Content.target_type == 'a_name', Content.target_ids.overlap(a_name_ids))
)
```

`a_name_ids` is a value which get fed into system from another api. It just so happened that the api has changed the value and it now contains big int and small int i.e., values like 30 and `5000002212222`. Due to this, my app is throwing an error that `operator does not exist: integer[] && bigint[]`

Whats the best way to solve this? Can i force sqlalchemy to cast all the values from `a_name_ids` to BigInt? Any other approach?

I believe we are using `sqlalchemy=1.1.18`.

The `Content.target_id` is defined as `target_ids = Column(ARRAY(sa.Integer))`. But changing this will require a big change on other platforms which are using this shared lib as well.

Comment: What's the type of `Content.target_ids`? integer or bigint?

Comment: Two thoughts: 1) There's no point checking if 5000002212222 overlaps with Content.target_ids - target_ids can only contain numbers up to 2147483647. This will always be false. 2) If you want to do this comparison anyway, you could [cast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12643646/sqlalchemy-postgresql-where-int-string) the column to a [BigInteger](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/type_basics.html#sqlalchemy.types.BigInteger).

Comment: @NickODell: Could you please add your comment as an answer. I am able to achieve what i wanted with option 2. perhaps you should share an example in answer for stackoverflow quality check.